# SQL "INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS" syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have this silly problem where MySQL server has issue with this command:

```
INSERT INTO ingridients (title,text) 
VALUES(?,`MISSING INFO`) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM ingridients WHERE title=?);
```

I receive following error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM ingridients WHERE title=?)' at line 1
```

I don't really use SQL too often so I can't find a way to fix this. Could someone help?

Comment: INSERT doesn't typically support a WHERE clause (although MySQL is not typical by any means). Have you tried checking the manual that corresponds to your MySQL version to see if it is in fact valid? You didn't include information on what version of MySQL you're using, so I can't help with a specific link, but your favorite search engine will be able to work with *MySQL documentation* as a search phrase.

Comment: If you use `WHERE title=?` shouldn't you do `UPDATE` instead?

Comment: @tcadidot0: The `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, means that `UPDATE` would not be applicable. You can't `UPDATE` a row that does not exist.

Comment: It appears that I'm using version 8.0 and going through the reference manual for INSERT I can't seem to find it being followed by WHERE clause, so I guess you're right that isn't supposed to work. Which leaves me again with problem of inserting a record only if it isn't already there.

Comment: Well, thats kind of strange . If so that's mean `INSERT` into two columns value only by excluding `id` from the insert. That means the values would be; assuming that the table have `id, title, text` column, the insert will be `NULL,?,'MISSING INFO'` of how many rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO ingridients (title,text) 
select ?,`MISSING INFO`
FROM ingridients
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM ingridients WHERE title=?);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery to check for existence:

```
INSERT INTO ingredients (title, text) 
    SELECT x.title, x.text
    FROM (SELECT ? as title, 'MISSING INFO' as text) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ingredients i WHERE i.title = x.title);
```

Actually, if you don't want duplicate titles, the right approach is to have the database validate data integrity using a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_ingredients_title on title(ingredients);

insert into ingredients (title, txt)
    values (?, 'MISSING INFO')
    on duplicate key update title = values(title);
```